# Open a window-popup from JMenuItem java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenuitem

I have a `JMenu` with a `JMenuItem`, and when I click on this, I need to open a `JFrame` or window, in other words a component with inside `JButton`, `JTextField`,...

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the `JFrame` in the same way you created your initial `JFrame`, and call

```
setVisible(true);
```

in the `ActionListener` of your `JMenuItem` to make it visible when the menu is clicked.

---

If you want it to be modal (original frame cannot be accessed unless the new window is closed), you can use a `JDialog` instead, setting `modal` to true in the constructor, or calling `setModal(true)`.

Comment: If i use a JFrame i got this error:
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container".
That's my code in actionPerformed method:
    PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setBounds(428, 99, 185, 155);

    final JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Button");
    button.setBounds(10, 93, 111, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);

    final Popup popup = factory.getPopup(null, frame, 200, 200);
    popup.show();

Comment: @enfix: You can also use `PopupFactory`, but in that case don't create a `JFrame` but a `JPanel` instead and add your components there.

Answer (score 0):

I write in answer for good code view:

If i use a JFrame i got this error:
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container".

That's my code in actionPerformed method:

```
PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setBounds(428, 99, 185, 155);

final JButton button = new JButton();
button.setText("Button");
button.setBounds(10, 93, 111, 25);
frame.getContentPane().add(button);

final Popup popup = factory.getPopup(null, frame, 200, 200);
popup.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing "popups" and "windows".

A popup is generally shown when you right click on some object. The popup will display a list of actions that can be performed on that object. For example a text field might have "cut", "copy" and "paste". Read the section from the Swing tutorial on "[Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup)" for more information.

A window is used to display other Swing components in a JFrame or JDialog.

Given that you are invoking this Action from a menu item I think you probably want to create and display a modal JDialog, not a JFrame or popup.

Also, while reading the tutorial, read the section on "Using Layout Managers". Using null layouts is not the best way to create a dialog.